# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError & conversion to dalvik format failed with error 1 unknown issue

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have a problem which basicly starts with me trying to add an external jar into an android project, everything seems good in eclipse untill i try to run the app then it crashes at the point where i try to call classes from the imported .jar with the error down below. I have tried to pinpoint the error but the only conclusion i have gottten to is that it has something to do with the .jar file i try to use not beeing included in the .apk.

However when i try the solutions that seems to match the "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError" problem either nothing happen or "conversion to dalvik format failed with error 1 unknown issue".

Im really stuck at this point because i have tried everything i could possibly find on the internet but nothing seems to work.

```
10-28 21:43:49.824: E/dalvikvm(5017): Could not find class 'Protocols.Client', referenced from method com.example.smarterhouse.MainActivity.onClick
10-28 21:43:49.824: W/dalvikvm(5017): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 6 (LProtocols/Client;) in Lcom/example/smarterhouse/MainActivity;
10-28 21:43:49.924: I/Adreno-EGL(5017): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:381>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: MINGHSUC_AU_LINUX_ANDROID_KK_2.7_RB1.04.04.02.007.047+PATCH[ES]_msm8960_refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_KK_2.7_RB1.04.04.02.007.047__release_ENGG ()
10-28 21:43:49.924: I/Adreno-EGL(5017): OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: 17.01.12.SPL
10-28 21:43:49.924: I/Adreno-EGL(5017): Build Date: 03/25/14 Tue
10-28 21:43:49.924: I/Adreno-EGL(5017): Local Branch: 
10-28 21:43:49.924: I/Adreno-EGL(5017): Remote Branch: refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_KK_2.7_RB1.04.04.02.007.047
10-28 21:43:49.924: I/Adreno-EGL(5017): Local Patches: c29912293421482fd51b7f36b91ae584f9993d66 Add support for KIT_KAT
10-28 21:43:49.924: I/Adreno-EGL(5017):                  4b5d3e5bcfa9d9563f740840d7258e1c1efa6d5a egl14: add EGL_ANDROID_image_crop support
10-28 21:43:49.924: I/Adreno-EGL(5017): Recon
10-28 21:43:51.706: W/dalvikvm(5017): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4168be18)
10-28 21:43:51.716: E/AndroidRuntime(5017): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-28 21:43:51.716: E/AndroidRuntime(5017): Process: com.example.smarterhouse, PID: 5017
10-28 21:43:51.716: E/AndroidRuntime(5017): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Protocols.Client
10-28 21:43:51.716: E/AndroidRuntime(5017):     at com.example.smarterhouse.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:79)
10-28 21:43:51.716: E/AndroidRuntime(5017):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4470)
10-28 21:43:51.716: E/AndroidRuntime(5017):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18593)
10-28 21:43:51.716: E/AndroidRuntime(5017):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
10-28 21:43:51.716: E/AndroidRuntime(5017):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10-28 21:43:51.716: E/AndroidRuntime(5017):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
10-28 21:43:51.716: E/AndroidRuntime(5017):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5867)
10-28 21:43:51.716: E/AndroidRuntime(5017):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-28 21:43:51.716: E/AndroidRuntime(5017):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-28 21:43:51.716: E/AndroidRuntime(5017):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
10-28 21:43:51.716: E/AndroidRuntime(5017):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:674)
10-28 21:43:51.716: E/AndroidRuntime(5017):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the issue was that the .jar i tried to use was compiled with java 8 and Thats not comparable with Android atm.

Answer (score 0):

As my opinion you should copy the .jar file and pasted it into libs folder if you use eclipse ide.

Comment: Tried that, and gets the "conversion to dalvik format failed with error 1 unknown" when i do